# Redis cluster and zsets

Tags: redis

In client side sharding approach I can create a shard and store a zset in that single shard. With Redis cluster, how big can a zset be? How do I scale zsets if is going to be an index of all the keys I have in redis.

Comment: Can you explain what your shard key is ? Also do you want to partition your zset across the shards or just the  elements partitioned across the shards. Because according to the docs here,  ___The partitioning granularity is the key, so it is not possible to shard a dataset with a single huge key like a very big sorted set__     .Check out the redis docs here : http://redis.io/topics/partitioning

Answer (score 13):

Short answer: yes - you can store all your key names in a single Sorted Set.

A Redis Sorted Set can have up to 2^32 - 1 (4294967295) members, each being made up of a string up to 512MB long and a 64bit score (the same limit goes for the number of keys in the database). This applies both to standalone Redis as well as Redis Cluster and allows storing ~2048PB in a single Sorted Set :)

In Redis Cluster, every key belongs to a specific hash slot. Therefore, a Sorted Set, regardless the theoretical size limits above, can only be as big as your biggest shard (i.e. Redis server). While a shard can manage a single slot, and a slot can hold a single key - I hardly recommend that approach due to scalability  concerns.

Indexing all your keys is an interesting challenge - why are you doing that? And more importantly, what types of queries do you want to run against that index? Depending on the number of keys in your database and querying requirements, there may be other, more efficient ways to achieve that.

Comment: If my command is "zadd to_be_expired 142791950 user1" then here the key is to_be_expired and the member is user1. If I add other members to the zset will they be stored on the same redis instance? So if I used a zset a single redis instance will be serving all the traffic right?

Comment: But if a single server gets hit with all the requests of frequent heartbeats that wouldn't be scalable.

Comment: It is what it is - a given Sorted Set (or any given key for that matter) resides in a single slot on a single shard.

Comment: So if it has to scale for writes I need to partition on my own the keys that would go in the sorted set correct?

Comment: The scale can be millions of customers

Comment: Indeed - partition the ZSET to buckets and manage multiple buckets across several shards. Using key hash tags you can essentially direct the relevant user keys to the same hash slots as the buckets'.